# Combining 2 private event subs

Tags: vba, excel

I need help in combining the 2 Private subs below. One is for time stamping in  column A if any cell in that row is modified or edited. The 2nd is for highlighting the modified row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column > 76 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells(Target.Row, 1) = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Sub
```

Can anyone suggest how to combine the `Worksheet_Change` subs?

Comment: did you mean soemthing like my code below ?

Comment: am unable to see any check mark near ur comments

Comment: see my edited answer (under **Appendix** I've added 2 screen-shots). you need to click on the **V** next to my answer, not my comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below to combine the 2 X `Worksheet_Change` event :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)

If Target.Column > 1 And Target.Column <= 76 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Running this code just now 13:46 time:

[image]

Comment: Hi, no its not working, it debugs in "Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)"

Comment: Please assist me

Comment: I am trying to, not sure why you are getting an error on that line ? you don't have `"` in the line, right ?

Comment: Yes sure. No "" in line. I just copy pasted your code in Private sub sheet and tried updating data in excel and is throws an error highlighting "Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)"

Comment: Try to add a `'` in the beginging of tha line, make it as a column, see if the rest of the code is working fine

Comment: Yes the time stamp works, but the particular edited column doesn't highlight

Comment: you wanted to highlight only the cell changed, not the column. How many cells are you trying to modify at once ? are you inserting data ? or deleting ?

Comment: There are columns from A:BJ, And Column A has the Statsu date which should be date stamped whenever any column from B:BJ is updated and Any cell from B-BJ should be highlighted if any modification is made in any of these cells. Yes, only the modifed cell to be highlighted not the column or row

Comment: see screen-shot I'v added above , just ran it now and it's working fine. Let's try somethng I usualy don't do : close Excel application. Open a new excel file from scratch, in 1 worksheet write the code above and test it.

Comment: Amazing, this works.... Thanks a lot for your help. and need one more Macro to be added with this. Need a macro to stop copy pasting values into a drop down list.  Tried this and this is working but need this one too to be added with my previous macro. Help me!

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xValue As String
    Dim xCheck1 As String
    Dim xCheck2 As String
    If Target.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        xValue                   = Target.Value
        On Error Resume Next
        xCheck1                  = Target.Validation.InCellDropdown
        On Error GoTo 0

Comment: Application.Undo
        On Error Resume Next
        xCheck2 = Target.Validation.InCellDropdown
        On Error GoTo 0
        If xCheck1 = xCheck2 Then
            Target = xValue
        Else
            MsgBox "No pasting allowed!"
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub

Comment: @ChandrasekarR sounds like a new SO post. please close this post, and mark as "ANSWER". In your new post describe what you are trying to achieve, add your relevant code, this will allow other users (besides me) helping you

Comment: @ChandrasekarR do you know how to mark as "ANSWER" ? you click on the **V** next to my post, it will trun green, and you earn +2 points

Comment: Oh ok, am new to this portal, will do now. thanks a lot

Comment: @ChandrasekarR try to make the minimal effort (after all my help) to mark as "ANSWER", just click on the check mark next to my answer above

Comment: @ChandrasekarR so ? did you try marking the **V** next to my answer here ? on the left side of my answer ?

Comment: @ChandrasekarR LOL :) yes you have